# Why remote notification action is doing nothing after clicking?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I have configured an action for a remote notification when it arrives to my iOs app. I want two different actions whether one key passed in the payload. The code seems to be executed, but the app doesn't open, nor the safari url. Here is my AppDelegate.m:

```
NSString *const NotificationCategoryOpenView  = @"openView";
NSString *const NotificationActionOpenView = @"View";

- (void)registerForNotification {
    UIApplication *application = [UIApplication sharedApplication];

    // iOs 8 or greater:

    if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerUserNotificationSettings:)]) {

        UIMutableUserNotificationAction *open;
        open = [[UIMutableUserNotificationAction alloc] init];
        [open setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
        [open setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil)];
        [open setIdentifier:NotificationActionOpenView];
        [open setDestructive:NO];
        [open setAuthenticationRequired:NO];

        UIMutableUserNotificationCategory *actionCategory;
        actionCategory = [[UIMutableUserNotificationCategory alloc] init];
        [actionCategory setIdentifier:NotificationCategoryOpenView];
        [actionCategory setActions:@[open] 
                        forContext:UIUserNotificationActionContextDefault];

        NSSet *categories = [NSSet setWithObject:actionCategory];
        UIUserNotificationType types = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|
                                        UIUserNotificationTypeSound|
                                        UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);

        UIUserNotificationSettings *settings;
        settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:types
                                                     categories:categories];

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    } else if ([application respondsToSelector:@selector(registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:)]) { 
        // iOs 7 or lesser:

        UIRemoteNotificationType myTypes = UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound;
        [application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:myTypes];
    }

}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

    if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionOpenView]) {

        NSDictionary *aps = userInfo[@"aps"];

        if ([[aps allKeys] containsObject:@"viewToOpen"]){
            NSString *webString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", aps[@"viewToOpen"]];
            NSURL *webURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:webString];

// This line doesn't work:
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:webURL];

        } else {
// These two lines doesn't work:
            UINavigationController *navigationController = (UINavigationController *)self.window.rootViewController;
            [navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
        }
    }

    completionHandler();

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: "Use `UserNotifications Framework's -[UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:]`" for iOS 10.0

Comment: True, another error was I was not taking care of iOS 10, thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler
```

And

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

Methods.

Notification activation mode is set to UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground,which Activate the app and put it in the background. If the app is already in the foreground, it remains in the foreground.So if you want to application in foreground/launch then use UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground

```
    [open setActivationMode:UIUserNotificationActivationModeBackground];
```

Use this activation option:

```
    [open setActivationMode: UIUserNotificationActivationModeForeground];
```

Check weather webUrl is proper and working as expected in normal flow.

For Xcode 8, u will have to migrate push notification using UserNotification framework.

Comment: The main problem was the ActivationMode, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be in this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo  {

    if(userInfo) {
        UIApplicationState state = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState];
        NSUInteger notificationType = [[userInfo valueForKey:API_NOTIFICATION_TYPE] integerValue];
        if (state == UIApplicationStateActive) {

            // Write code which should work when notification comes and app is active
            }
            else {
                // Write code which should work when notification comes and app is in background or inactive or terminated
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method will get called only

1. when app is ACTIVE and notification comes
2. when app is in background or inactive or terminated and notifications comes and user taps on it